# Why firepath is not able to see deep xpath?

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, xpath, firepath

everybody! 
I am using Firefox browser and Chrome one. 
I installed FireBug and FirePath to Firefox. 
I can see html tree in Chrome deeper than in Firefox.
I am looking for span values: [image: Chrome]

FirePath hellps me to looking for values, cuz it flashs the correct one.
So, I can see only this in Firefox:

```
<ul class="sport--list">
<li class="sport--block">
<li class="sport--block">
<li class="sport--block">
<li class="sport--block">
<div class="sport--head sp--bg sp_2 head--folding folding--open">
<ul class="category--list--block">
<li class="category--block sp_2">
<div class="caterory--head">
<ul class="events--list">
<li>
<div class="event--head-block" style="height: 48px;"/>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I am not able to go deeper than: `<div class="event--head-block" style="height: 48px;"/>`

And I use this xpath: `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='sport--list']/li[contains(div/span, 'Теніс')]/ul/li/ul/li/div/div/div/div/span"));`

It gives mee this error at Visual Studio:

```
{"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"xpath\",\"selector\":\"//ul[@class='sport--list']/li[contains(div/span, 'Теніс')]/ul/li/ul/li/div/div/div/div/span\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.170)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)"}
```

How so? I can see full HTML chrome, and I use Chrome driver, anyway my attempts are unsuccessful. I want to get span values and then add them to list. 
Thanks a lot for your time for me.

Comment: Did you try `Element Inspector`?

Comment: Yes, I pressed F12